# Use a PHP router from a directory

Tags: php, url-rewriting, fat-free-framework

I have a dedicated server with apache installed on it.

I have different websites in separated folders and I can access it like this:
www.example.com/folder1
www.example.com/folder2
...

But in a file, I use a framework (F3).
The router creates a 404 error when I try something like www.example.com/f3/my/route
How can I change this without creating an alias?

See my /f3/.htaccess :

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#

RewriteBase /f3/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Thanks,

Romain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htacces file, add a rewritebase with the folder name:

```
RewriteBase /f3/
```

Comment: @4z3rty well then you are going to need to show some code else its just a guess

Comment: I have added my .htaccess in my post.

Comment: Ok, well that seems fine, but there could be any number of other errors. Does you code work OK if it is run from webroot, eg example.com (not a subfolder)? If not then the folder is unrelated

Comment: No, f3 is in the default folder (/var/www/f3).
And I developed with an alias and my routes worked...

Comment: I edited my apache configuration for changed AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All and It works !